# Disable Advertising Affiliate Pop-Under on Mobile Device

Tags: wordpress, jquery-mobile, mobile

I have an adult wordpress blog and I am using juicyads as my affiliate advertising network. I have one pop-under which I would like to disable on mobile devices only because I realized it is a big nuisance for the mobile visitor which will hurt my traffic.

The script is in the header and begins and ends as below:

```
<!-- Begin JuicyAds PopUnder Code -->
<script type="text/javascript">juicy_code='9454y2u2w256r2r2s2c42354';             
<!-- End JuicyAds PopUnder Code -->
```

Is there any way I can modify it so it does not appear on mobile visits? Thank you.

Kind regards,

Pintersex

Answer (score 0):

Replace the code with this:

```
<div id="mobile-popup">
<script type="text/javascript">juicy_code='9454y2u2w256r2r2s2c42354';
</script>
</div>
```

Add this to CSS

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    #mobile-popup {
        display:none;
    }
}
```